# JavaScript get remote host name

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file that a user can include via CDN.

Let's say The CDN URL is http://somecdnsite.com/myfile.js

In this file I have console.log(location.hostname)

The client is serving it from localhost:8000

In the file I am getting location.hostname, which is grabbing the clients host URL. (localhost)What I really want is for the file to output the remote hostname "somecdnsite.com" where the file is actually sitting. Can this be achieved? And how?

Comment: Sure, just hardcode that URL in a variable in your file, you know where you're hosting it, right!

Comment: `the file to output the remote hostname` - output in what way?

Comment: within the hosted script - `document.currentScript` is (shockingly enough) the current script element (only when loading, not when in a callback for example) see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)

Comment: You can look at the `<script>` tags in the DOM.

Comment: ^ that's a good idea, would get you the URL from the source

Comment: Depending on the environment where the CDN is sitting, I need a dynamic way to get the remote host name to pass to the client to be able to hit the node API. The client can't hit the middleware via localhost/API so when I try to set apihost=location.hostname + '/api' in the CDN file I need it to return the .com address not the localhost from client :-(

Comment: Wouldn't you want a fixed URL for your API?

Comment: Can't do that because it can get deployed to 4 possible environments and sits on a load balancer.

Comment: Uhm, what? And you don't want a fixed url for that load balancer either, but four different URL's for the same API?

Comment: If the same code base is deployed to 4 different environments, I need a dynamic way that is can get the correct URL for the environment it is on. Easy of self hosted, just location.hostname, but when that JavaScript file is hit via remote client, that won't work anymore.

Comment: Adeneo example?

Comment: Because the node server is running on the remote client. I need a dynamic way to tell the remote client which URL it is on in order to hit the node API correctly. If I simply put /URL that will not work if I'm on a remote CDN it will try to resolve to localhost/API which doesn't exist. Yes I could hard code the URL but that does me no good when the code gets deployed to different environments.

Comment: Not really making enough sense.

Comment: Let's say I have 3 domains. Domain1.com and so on. The CDN file could live on any one of those. If I'm referencing the CDN file from somewebsite.com let's say I have a console logg for location.hostname. It's going to show the somewebsite.com but instead how can I show the domain1, 2, or 3 to validate which CDN the client hit?

Comment: If we could just stick to the question instead of wondering why I need it that would help. Also document .currentScript doesn't work in IE

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this, it is because of JS file download from cdn or remote server to local machine browser and local machine will execute it, that why 
location.hostname refer to local host.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue...

```
  var target = document.currentScript || (function() {
     var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
     return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
  })();
```

I am able to get the host name name of the scripts host.